# Cannot find Titanium CLI

Tags: node.js, titanium, npm, homebrew

I ran off this cmd after switching node versions for use with Titanium studio.

```
sudo npm install -g alloy titanium
```

However even though it appears to install. Neither alloy nor titanium seem to be linked to my bash profile.

I tried:

```
dave:~ $ titanium -v
-bash: titanium: command not found
```

Node and npm were originally installed with homebrew and I now have both 0.10.2 and 0.8.22 packages.

I also cannot launch the app in the SDK due to the fact it cannot find the titanium CLI.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem.

Screenshot of actual error http://cl.ly/image/1j1T3U2n2h0L

Comment: is your titanium studio updated to the latest version

Comment: Hello David, Firstly you check your titanium studio is updated and then after check you internet connect... some time this problem occur due to slow net connection..

Comment: check if the installation location of the packages are in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The Titanium CLI requires Node.js 0.10.x or newer to be installed

> reference: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium

Answer (score 0):

Before using the Titanium CLI to create and build Titanium projects, you need to make sure your development environment is correctly configured.

For reference please visit official documentation.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_CLI_Tasks